# Creating a Gradle-Maven C/C++ package without Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle

I am working on a library written mostly in C, which I'd like to publish gradle-maven packages for, without actually using Gradle itself.

The project currently uses [waf](http://waf.io) as its build system and I cannot switch, since most other build system - which I tried - tend to cause more problems than any good.

However, I still would like to provide pre-compiled maven packages for gradle users to consume. So far, I figured out, that I need following files:

- `<module-name>-<config>-<version>.module`
- `<module-name>-<config>-<version>.pom`

I managed to instruct my build system to generate these files. What I am missing is the overall process.

(*TL;DR*)

**What would be the overall steps required to create a C++ maven package for gradle using the command line tools (e.g. vim + maven) only?**

The goal is to contribute to the realm of gradle's native packages without being confined within it.